# Flask-sqlalchemy: cannot give property field to constructor as keyword argument

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm reading the "Flask Web Development" book and creating a similar application to flasky (https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky). I have set up a User model:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from app import db


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String)

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is read-only')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return verify_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
```

Now in the signup view I do:

```
user = User(email=form.email.data, username=form.username.data,
                password = form.password.data)
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'
```

Strangely enough, the tutorial project does the same, see https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/auth/views.py, on line 54.

It works when I do this:

```
user = User(email=form.email.data, username=form.username.data)
user.password = form.password.data
```

But I would like to be able to pass the password to the constructor. Apparently flask_sqlalchemy does not understand that the password is a property. But how come this works in the tutorial? I cannot find the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overrode `__init__` but didn't allow for a password:

```
def __init__(self, username, email):
    self.username = username
    self.email = email
```

There is no need to override `__init__` as the default SQLAlchemy model provides one that accepts all the fields already.  Simply delete the `__init__` declaration and things should *just work*.

In the [code from the book](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/657cf1c8b5798ff0341390d5929d86b7e9ae0637/app/models.py#L120-130) Michael *does* override the `__init__` method, but he accepts all keyword arguments and the first thing he does is forward them on to the super constructor (to preserve SQLAlchemy's default behavior.)

Comment: Wow.. I'm ashamed now.. can't believe I missed that :( Thank you!